# How to access an object from another class?

Tags: php, class

I have a database class, which is used to make select, update, delete [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) queries.

Now, I want to create a MySQL query inside another class, but if I define `$db = new DB();` in `index.php`, I can't use the `$db` var in another class. Do I have to define the variable `$db` over and over again, if I want to make a query? Or is there a way to make the `$db` var with an object global var?

Answer (score 12):

The cleanest approach would be to [aggregate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Aggregation) the database class where needed by [injecting](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) it. All other approaches, like using the [`global`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword or using [`static`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) methods, let alone a Singleton, is introducing tight coupling between your classes and the global scope which makes the application harder to test and maintain. Just do

```
// index.php
$db  = new DBClass;               // create your DB instance
$foo = new SomeClassUsingDb($db); // inject to using class
```

and

```
class SomeClassUsingDb
{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Use [Constructor Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/) if the dependency is required to create a valid state for the instance. If the dependency is optional or needs to be interchangeable at runtime, use Setter Injection, e.g.

```
class SomeClassUsingDb
{
    protected $db;
    public function setDb($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how exactly do I use the $db var than? $this->db->select(); ?

Comment: @Mike yes, exactly like this. Or through a getter (if you wrote one)

Answer (score 5):

You probably want a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This gives you a way to get an instance of DB anywhere in the code. Then anywhere you want to do a query, first do `$db = DB::getInstance();`.

An alternative is [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which passes a DB instance to all classes which need one.

Comment: An example for the singleton pattern in php can be found here: http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4002.html

Comment: To make an object globally available you only need a static method to instantiate it. It does not have to be Singleton. Both is smelly, so Dependency Injection is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php` file use

```
require_once('path_to_file_with_class.php');
```

You may also use `include_once`, which will give you a warning instead of an error if the 'path_to_file_with_class.php' file is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Define it on a class (separate [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file). Then require it for every PHP file the var is needed in.

Answer (score 0):

First make your database class a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). And then in your new class you can do something like:

```
class myNewClass{
  private $_db;

  public function  __construct(){
     $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic function `__autoload()`.

Answer (score -1):

You might define it as global in your index.php file, and in the class constructor also put `$this->db &= $GLOBALS['db'];`