# what is the difference between -> and =>? what is ::?

Tags: php

Im a bit new to javascript and I am trying to understand how backbone.js and understand how it works, however there are times that I run into lines like this:

```
"admin"=>password_hash("pass",PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

I understand this code is crypting the pass however i dont understand the => symbol.

Furthermore, I have encountered the :: and I dont understand it either.

Anyone know where I can read about this better? I have been searching but I have been unsuccessful to find any tutorial that explains it clearly.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like PHP. Where exactly did you see that?

Comment: it is PHP, missed that, ive been reading this for a while now. Im trying to understand how Phreeze works . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks more like PHP. You can start here [PHP.NET](http://www.php.net)

[As for :: take a look at this (:: used in Classes )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776788/best-practice-on-php-singleton-classes)

[Logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) 

[Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)