# Where to save the model - Yii

Tags: php, yii, model

I've recently been introduced to the concept of Saving the model that I've updated. In this case, I have created a function called incrementPayList which takes in the id of a list and the increments it by one.

This is the code for the function in the paylist model

```
public function incrementPayList($id) 
{
    $results = Recipient::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"list_id = $id"));
    $count = count ( $results );
    $this->num_indv = $count + 1;         
}
```

Now in the  recipient controller, I am calling this function. The recipient holds all of the individuals who are connected to a certain payList

```
 */
public function actionCreate($id)
{
    $model=new Recipient;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Recipient']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Recipient'];

        Paylist::model()->incrementPayList($id);
        if($model->save())
        {
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'id'=>$id
    ));
}
```

I know that the `$count` returns the correct number - but it is not saving that count in the field num_indv. I have an inkling that this is because I am not saving the new PayList model. However, how/where should I do this? Should I do it inside the function itself? Or should I do it in the controller? But, if I do it in the controller, I can't simply use `$model->save()` because it is not the same model.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is that you aren't running `incrementPayList` on the Paylist instance `$model` but on the `Recipient` singleton (see [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern?rq=1) and [Best practice on PHP singleton classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776788/best-practice-on-php-singleton-classes) for more information).

Your code should read:

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Recipient'];
$model->incrementPayList($id);
if($model->save())
    {
```

Also use [`CActiveRecord::count()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#count-detail) instead of  `findAll` followed by `count($results)` since you only need the number and not the items themselves.

Comment: How would 
$model->incrementPayList($id); work if $model is a formed as a new Recipient model. Are you saying that I should house incrementPayList in the recipient model then?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `incrementPayList` sets the `num_indv` for a single record. Each `CActiveRecord` represents a record therefore it should be called from `$model` and not `Recipient::model()`

Answer (score 0):

you can save like this

```
$modelPaylist = new Paylist;

    if(modelPaylist->save())....
```

Comment: Is this in the model or in the controller?

Comment: In  recipient controller