# Call parent property from child class without parent::__construct

Tags: php, oop, parent-child

I've got a parent class `My_Admin` with a public property `$options`

I've got a child class `My_Notices` that needs to access the `$options` property.

If, in the child class, I throw `parent::__construct()` into the child class's `__construct()`, I am able to access `$options` *BUT* it duplicates the entire output of the parent class. In other words, I'm getting two html page outputs on the same page, because of the instantiation of the child class calling `parent::_construct()`.

I've tried declaring `$options` in my child construct like `public function __construct($options)` but then it tells me:

`Warning: Missing argument 1 for My_Notices::__construct()`

** EDIT **

Here's a breakdown of the classes:

```
class My_Admin
{
    private $sections;
    protected $settings;
    protected $defaults;
    public $options;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->settings = array();
        $this->get_settings();
        $this->defaults = array( /* stuff here */ );
        $this->sections = array( /* stuff here */ );
        add_filter('plugin_action_links', array($this, 'pluginpage'), 10, 2);
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'menu'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'deregister'), 20);
        add_action('wp_ajax_my_save', array($this, 'save'));
        if(!get_option('my_options')) $this->initialize();
        $this->options = get_option('my_options');
    }
}
class My_Notices extends My_Admin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'baseconfig'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'baseignore'));
    }
    public function baseconfig(){
        global $pagenow;
        $uid = get_current_user_id();
        /* I NEED TO ACCESS $options HERE */
        if(!$this->options['base1'] || !$this->options['bs1name'])
        {
            if(!get_user_meta($uid, 'my_notice'))
            {   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not do like `class My_notices extends My_Admin {}` and then just use `$this->options`?

Comment: Sorry I don't really see any real question. Not quite sure what you want to achieve and where your problem is.

Comment: yes I've done that. I figured that was assumed in the designation child class.

Comment: the question is the title of the post. Call parent property from child class without parent::__construct. Obviously, my question is: how?

Comment: or you could add a method to your My_Admin class to get the admin instance and access the public property that way?

Comment: I thought that child classes were supposed to inherit parent properties. I didn't think I would need to create a whole method just to access them.

Comment: When is defined your parent's `$option`?

Comment: parent property $options is declared before __construct() and defined inside __construct()

Comment: So, you have a `$this->option = something;` in your parent's `__construct()`. But when you call to your parent then it prints some strings because you have `echo` in the parent's `__construct()`. Is it correct?

Comment: Not quite. I don't do any echos in the parent __construct(), but it does call methods which echo html to the page.

Comment: Why is the constructor printing things?

Comment: It's not really printing anything, but it's calling hooks like add_action('whatever', 'mymethod') which do print things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, according to your comments you need call your parent's without print. You need use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-end-clean.php), but you should see if your logic is correct because if the parent's class prints text is not the best.

```
class My_Notices extends My_Admin {
      public __construct(){
          ob_start(); // prevents prints.
          parent::__construct();
          ob_end_clean(); // clear the capture

          // Your code here....
```

**UPDATED**:
Also you can check if it is the parent and then print:

```
class My_Admin
{
    private $sections;
    protected $settings;
    protected $defaults;
    public $options;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->settings = array();
        $this->get_settings();
        $this->defaults = array( /* stuff here */ );
        $this->sections = array( /* stuff here */ );

        if( !is_subclass_of($this, 'My_Admin' ) ) { // Is the parent
            add_filter('plugin_action_links', array($this, 'pluginpage'), 10, 2);
            add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'menu'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue'));
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'deregister'), 20);
            add_action('wp_ajax_my_save', array($this, 'save'));
       }

        if(!get_option('my_options')) $this->initialize();
        $this->options = get_option('my_options');
    }
    public function get_settings(){}
    public function initialize(){}
}
class My_Notices extends My_Admin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'baseconfig'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'baseignore'));

    }
}
```

See how works: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4ed5143244aaf0c57b29ff8487d911ab7cf99dd

Comment: I like this idea but it still outputs duplicate content. :(

Comment: If you use `ob_end_clean` the capture is deleted and finished. Can you do debug to search where is printing?

Comment: I don't really know. I did it exactly as you have above, but it still output duplicate html on the page. I will edit the OP with more info.

Comment: I added a big chunk to the OP above.

Comment: If you put my code before your `add_action` in My_Notices, is the page printed twice? If it's true then something o your `add_action` is printing twice the page. With `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean` nothing is showed. Test to put the `ob_end_clean` to end of your `script` and you will see nothing is showed.

Comment: I did this: 
`ob_start(); parent::__construct(); add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'baseconfig')); add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'baseignore')); ob_end_clean();`
And it still outputs duplicate content.

Comment: So I think the solution I'm looking for is to be able to do it without parent::__construct(). Seems like I should be able to somehow.

Comment: I have tried and it is working fine. The problem is not the `__construct()`. Test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/195a9e85e7f5198a3d813d0ff7719202ba592dc8. You can comment the `ob_end_clean()` line and the parent prints too.

Comment: Your sandbox showed me why. You are only instantiating the child class in the global space. I was instantiating the parent and the child. But that raises the question, what if I have a second class that extends My_Admin? I wouldn't be able to instantiate it and My_Notices without duplicating the parent output again. Seems counterintuitive. Maybe I should just avoid child/parent classes until I figure out what real benefit they have.

Comment: Now I can instantiate both parent and child in the global space and access parent's options without any difficulty. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid your double creations, this might be the route you have to take:

Add these to your My_Admin class:

make a `private static $self;` property.

in your `__construct()` method add `self::$self = &$this;`

make a method:

```
public static getInstance(){
    return $self;
}
```

in My_Notices add this where you need to access the options property:

```
$my_admin = My_Admin::getInstance();
$my_admin->options;
```

Comment: But he doesn't want a [`singleton`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8776814/2389232)... It's a `bad practice`.

Comment: Also following this to the letter got me a fatal error:
`Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: My_Admin::$self`