# Singleton pattern example in PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm a PHP newbie.
Here is a standart Singleton pattern example according to [phptherightway.com](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html):

```
<?php
class Singleton
{
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if (null === $instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    private function __wakeup()
    {
    }
}

class SingletonChild extends Singleton
{
}

$obj = Singleton::getInstance();
var_dump($obj === Singleton::getInstance());             // bool(true)

$anotherObj = SingletonChild::getInstance();
var_dump($anotherObj === Singleton::getInstance());      // bool(false)

var_dump($anotherObj === SingletonChild::getInstance()); // bool(true)
```

The question is in this line:

```
        static $instance = null;
        if (null === $instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }
```

So as i understand `if (null === $instance)` is always TRUE, because everytime i'm calling the method `getInstance()` the variable `$instance` is always being set to `null` and a new instance will be always created.
So this is not really a singleton. Could you please explain me ?

Comment: Just in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776788/best-practice-on-php-singleton-classes

Comment: static $instance = null; will be executed only on first function call - at others it will be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at "Example #5 Example use of static variables" here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

"Now, $a is initialized only in first call of function and every time the test() function is called it will print the value of $a and increment it."

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

```
static $instance = null;
```

will be runned only on first function invoke

> Now, $a is initialized only in first call of function

and all other time it will store created object